# Roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Suppose that $f(i)=0$, where $i^2=-1$. 
Can I conclude that $x^2+1$ is a factor of $f(x)$? If so, how can be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the remainder factor theorem.

**Hint:** Apply the conjugate root theorem.

Comment: $f(i)=0\rightarrow x-i$ divides $f\rightarrow x+i$ divides $f\rightarrow (x+i)(x-i)=x^2+1$ divides $f$?

Comment: @bateman Indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if not, then $i$ is a root of the linear $\,f\ {\rm mod}\ (x^2\!+\!1) = f - (x^2\!+\!1)g \ne 0,\ $ so $\, i\in \Bbb Q.$